# An issue with the TLocationSensor?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

In my program (using Delphi 10.1 Berlin, Update 2 - application is FireMonkey), I have used a TLocationSensor. There is no event handler assigned to the event `OnLocationChanged`:
[image: Screenshot of TLocationSensor Events]

Even so, my app throws an error. I turned on debug and found that the following code in System.Sensors is being executed:

```
procedure TCustomLocationSensor.DoLocationChanged(const OldLocation,
  NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D);
begin
  if Assigned(OnLocationChanged) and not (SameValue(OldLocation.Latitude, NewLocation.Latitude) and
    SameValue(OldLocation.Longitude, NewLocation.Longitude)) then
    OnLocationChanged(Self, OldLocation, NewLocation);
end;
```

For some reason, it is trying to trigger OnLocationChanged. But it should not be trying to trigger this event given that I have not assigned an event handler to it.

I have now explicitly set `OnLocationChanged:=nil;` in my Form's `OnCreate` event. This seems to address the issue (but I would prefer to not have this code since it feels like I am addressing an issue that should not be happening).

I guess my question is: Am I missing something? Or is there an issue with the TLocationSensor?

Comment: The `OnLocationChanged` field is nilled at the creation of the `TLocationSensor` instance. If `OnLocationChanged` is non-nil at a later stage, something in your program is changing it. That something may be your code or some third party. But hard to say anything more, you did not even indicate what error you got. Also nothing about target platform, tested device etc.

Comment: Just to clarify, the fact that the IDE shows `OnLocationChanged` unassigned does of course not mean that it couldn't be assigned in code. Put a breakpoint in `procedure TLocationSensor.SetOnLocationChanged(const Value: TLocationChangedEvent);`. The call stack will tell you who is setting it. The procedure is in unit `System.Sensors.Components`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @TomBrunberg. The error was an access violation error. I am currently testing the application on Windows 10 running on a Lenovo Ideapad.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I used the breakpoint as you suggested. It gets called in a completely different window (with its own Location sensor component). In that window, I do use the OnLocationChanged event. But why would the component in the main form continue to persist the event handler assignment to a completely separate instance of the component in a different form?

Comment: Ok, yes, you are missing somethings ;) 1) Complete error messages are crucial for error analysis. 2) All instances of a given class share the same code (but each have their own data). It is the other `TLocationSensor` that triggers the AV error. If the access address in the error is a fairly small number (close to $00000000) then the real error is most probably accessing an non-instantiated object instance.

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me @TomBrunberg :)  (1) Unfortunately I can no longer recreate the error after I made the fix to not use the event handler. (2) I am quite clear about the way object instances work, which is why this defect bugs me. The second form that I open is a modal form which is Freed after use. I would think that the Location sensor object on that form will get released along with freeing the form. As such, there should be no remnants of the event handler assignment from the modal form. The error triggers on the Main form. That is what is confusing to me.